# Ember Template Not showing in page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple blog with Ember.  I'm following this tutorial https://emberway.io/a-gentle-introduction-to-ember-2-0-8ef1f378ee4

I've created a model and generated a template.bhs and component.js for 'create-new-post'.  I've created a route for 'posts' and also 'posts/new'.  However, when loading 'app.com/posts/new' in the browser, I don't see the content from `new.hbs`I just see my header and footer as per `application.hbs`.

No doubt I'm missing something very basic here.

**templates/posts/new.hbs**

```
{{#create-new-post}}{{/create-new-post}}
```

**components/create-new-post/template.hbs**

```
<h3>Create a new post</h3> <form>   <p>
{{input value=post.title placeholder="Post title"}}
{{input value=post.text placeholder="Text"}}   </p>   <p>
{{textarea value=post.text placeholder="Content"}}   </p>   <p>
<span {{action "createPost" post}}>Publish</span>   </p> </form>
```

**routes/new.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

**models/post.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  snippet: DS.attr('string'),
  createdDate: DS.attr('date'),
  text: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Comment: Do you have {{outlet}} in posts template and in application.hbs?

Comment: I somehow didn't have it in posts template.  Thanks!

Comment: @JovicaŠuša do you want to post that as the answer

Comment: Sure, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `{{outlet}}` in posts or application template.